# jquery problem with live

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code like this:

```
$(".delete").live('click', function() {    
    var commentContainer = $(this).parent();
    var id = $(this).attr("id");            
    var string = 'id='+ id ;
    $.ajax({   
        url: "<?php echo site_url('messages/delete') ?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: string,
        cache: false,
        success: function(){
            commentContainer.slideUp('600', function() {$(this).remove();
                $('.messages').fadeOut('2000', function(){$(this).remove();
                    $('#messages').load("<?php echo site_url('messages/show') ?>", function(){
                        $(this).fadeIn('2000')
                    });
                }); 
            });             
        } 
    });
    return false;
});
$('.delete').confirm(
{
    msg: 'You are about to delete this message. Are you sure?<br>',
    buttons: {
    separator: ' - '
    }
});//message deleting
```

When activated for the first time it is working (when I try to delete message, question is asked and if I say yes, message is deleted). When data again shown, when I click delete it is deleting message without asking. What is the problem?

Comment: If you could post a link or create a jsfiddle, that would be helpful

Comment: At the moment I am working on a local host, and I am using codeigniter. http://jsfiddle.net/Bravat/YaMUY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'll have to register the confirm plugin after every ajax load as it isn't using live internally.

Easiest way would be to move the code into its own function and call that inside the load callback and on page load.

```
function deleteConfirmSetup() {
   $('.delete').confirm(
   {
        msg: 'You are about to delete this message. Are you sure?<br>',
        buttons: {
            separator: ' - '
        }
    });//message deleting
}   

$(".delete").live('click', function() {    
    $.ajax({   
       url: "<?php echo site_url('messages/delete') ?>",
       type: "POST",
       data: string,
       cache: false,
       success: function(){
          commentContainer.slideUp('600', function() {$(this).remove();
             $('.messages').fadeOut('2000', function(){$(this).remove();
                $('#messages').load("<?php echo site_url('messages/show') ?>", function(){
                    $(this).fadeIn('2000');
                    deleteConfirmSetup(); // Add function call here
                });
            }); 
        });             
    } 
  });
  return false;
});
deleteConfirmSetup(); // Also call function here to setup initially
```

Comment: I am new to JS and JQ, and at the moment I don't know what to do, and I am bit confused. Created function like this: `   function delete_message(){
       $('.delete').confirm(
    {
        msg: 'You are about to delete this message. Are you sure?<br>',
        buttons: {
        separator: ' - '
        }
    });//message deleting 
   }` and added onClick="delete_message();" to the a tag(used for deleting), but now it is deleting without question???

Comment: @Sasha I have edited my answer to show what I meant. (I stripped out a bit of your code as it was long, so don't copy and paste the whole lot)

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the "confirm" plugin doesn't operate with `live` and instead is using `bind`.

When the element is added, it doesn't have the confirmation bindings but does have the live ones, so it'll just delete.

You could attempt to re-call the confirm plugin in your success function after the new content is loaded, modify the plugin, do it yourself manually, or find a new plugin that's a bit better thought-out.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the confirm plugin, but a slightly irritating hack to make this work as you want might be to do this:

```
var bindBackup = jQuery.fn.bind;
jQuery.fn.bind = jQuery.fn.live;
```

before you run `.confirm()`. Then just restore it afterwards:

```
jQuery.fn.bind = bindBackup;
```

I haven't tried it, but the `live` function [doesn't](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=jQuery.fn.live) implement `bind` in it's source, so I don't see a reason why it won't work.

Comment: Nevermind... just had a go and it won't work because the `confirm` plugin doesn't apply  `bind` directly from the selector. I'll keep this here for reference, trusting that no-one will down-vote it!

Comment: I am doing something wrong. I added this at the beginning and now there is a question but if I click ether yes or no, nothing happens???

Comment: Even the way I presented this is a light hack, and to get it working will require a lot more hacking. I'd recommend using @Richard's answer over this one.